# Equation with complex numbers: having a complex variable in the denominator

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to solve the following equation:

$ |\frac{1}{z}| = |z-1|$

My attempt was to make $z= x + iy$ but I get to a very complex equation 
$x^2+y^2 = (x^2 - 2x +1 +y^2)(x^4 +2x^2y^2 + y^4)$

I was wondering if there is a simpler way to do this. I also thought of making $|\frac{1}{z}| = |\frac{\overline{z}}{z\overline{z}}|$ but I don't feel it's gonna help me? Can someone give a hint? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are actually infinitely many $z$ which satisfy your equation. It's equivalent to 
$$ 1 = | z^2 - z|,$$
so you can find solutions by using the quadratic formula on
$$ z^2 - z + c = 0,$$
where $c$ is any complex number with $|c| = 1$.